# Is it possible to use one .net ASP MVC Controller for two "Panels"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am learning the learning the asp mvc pattern and am a little lost on controllers. The web page I am building needs to have a search "Panel" on the left, and a data window on the right.

Is this the task for one controller or two? What I need is the user to enter data on the search panel, click go and then display results in that panel.

That all seems pretty easy under one controller but...

I want to click on one of the results in the search panel and display their data in the right panel but is that the job for a new controller? It seems like two controllers intuitively to control each panel but is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing could be achieved numerous ways, but it sounds a bit like you're thinking of a 'controller' like a page.  A controller contains multiple methods, each of which will execute an action (which possibly could be a page rendering).  A controller does not represent a web page, but a collection of actions performed (redirects, GET's, POSTS, etc...).

> I want to click on one of the results in the search panel and display their data in the right panel but is that the job for a new controller? It seems like two controllers intuitively to control each panel but is that even possible?

1. No, this is probably not the job of a new controller.
2. Yes, but probably not what you want.

Chances are you'll only have one controller, but two methods for the Get and Post phase of searching.  How you populate each panel brings up a lot of questions:

- Will you force a page refresh on searching?
- Ajax reload?
- Heaven forbid, frames?
- Javascript panel?

Perhaps the easiest to start with is the first option - forcing a page refresh on search.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // GET
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string searchWord)
    {
        // Perform whatever steps involved in finding things
        IEnumerable<MyResults> results = _service.Search(searchWord);

        // Pass the result into the view
        return View(results);
    }
}
```

Then a quick and easy view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyResults>

<div id="panel_1">
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="searchWord" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
}
</div>

<div id="panel_2">
    @if(Model != null)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach(var result in Model)
            {
                <li>@result.Name</li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

From here, hooking it up with Ajax is fairly straight forward.

**Edit - Step 2 - ajax stuff.**

Controller actions don't have to return a whole view - they can return a partial to an ajax request.

So, add a partial at least for panel 2:

Index.cshtml:

```
@*
    Panel 1 remains the same.  Or could move it do it's own partial and
    render it via Html.RenderPartial("Panel1")
*@
<div id="panel_1">
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type="text" name="searchWord" />
        <button type="submit">Go</button>
    }
</div>

@* This is now just a placeholder since it will be populated via ajax. *@
<div id="panel_2"></div>
```

Create a new view, Panel2.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyResults>

@if(Model != null)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach(var result in Model)
        {
            <li>@result.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <i>Nothing found</i>
}
```

Then change the controller action:

```
// POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string searchWord)
{
    // Perform whatever steps involved in finding things
    IEnumerable<MyResults> results = _service.Search(searchWord);

     // Pass the result into the partial view for panel 2
     return View("Panel2", results);
}
```

The only left is some javascript to link it all together (can't quite do this all off the top of my head)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panel_1 form').submit(function() {
        $.post({
            url: this.action,
            success: function(response) {
                // Replace the contents in panel 2
                $('#panel_2).html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It is beginning to clear up. 

Does this imply that a there will be a single View that has both panels? It sounds like you would recommend building the page with refreshes, then build in partial page rendering? The ultimate goal is to have no page refreshes but that could be ambitious for the first iteration.

Comment: Question 1 - Yes, one view to renders the whole page, then partials.  Question 2 - Yes - at least this is how my usual workflow goes.  Ensure the actions and database layers are working, then do the fanciness.  Typically it's pretty easy too.  I'll edit my answer further to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

Both your search panel and your output (results) panel seem to be in a search 'context'.  It's perfectly acceptable to have these handled by the same controller.

When people are beginning MVC they got a lot of advice to have a controller for each Entity.  This is good advice to learn MVC in a CRUD context but can lead to a little bit of confusion when moving passed Entity CRUD.

Go with SearchController in your case.

Comment: Thank You! They will be a single a view? or can a single controller have two views open on the page?

Comment: Yes, they will be 'contained' in a single view.  However, you can break the two 'panels' up into partial views.  Research @Html.Partial(...)